# How to calculate the difference between last and first object in array

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to calculate the difference between the keys/values of the last object and the keys/values of the first object. If the length of the object is 1 returns object.
Objects are in data array.

**Example**

```
var arr = [
    {"year":"2019","data":[{"a":7,"b":10,"c":13}]}
   ,{"year":"2020","data":[{"a":15,"b":30,"c":35},{"a":44,"b":55,"c":66},{"a":15,"b":29,"c":36}]}
   ,{"year":"2021","data":[{"a":12,"b":14,"c":16},{"a":44,"b":55,"c":66},{"a":14,"b":16,"c":26}]}
]
```

**I expect this result**

```
[{"year":"2019","data":{"a":7,"b":10,"c":13}}
,{"year":"2020","data":{"a":0,"b":-1,"c":1}}
,{"year":"2021","data":{"a":2,"b":2,"c":10}}]
```

**My attempt**

```
  const output = arr.map(o=>({
      year: o.year          
     ,data: o.data.reduce((x,y)=>{
      return {
         a: (+x.a.length - 1) - +y.a[0]
        ,b: (+x.b.length - 1) - +y.b[0]
        ,c: (+x.c.length - 1) - +y.c[0]
        }})                
  }))
```

I get this log:

```
[{"year":"2019","data":{"a":null,"b":null,"c":null}}
,{"year":"2020","data":{"a":null,"b":null,"c":null}}
,{"year":"2021","data":{"a":null,"b":null,"c":null}}]
```

**Updated**

The solutions offered by Greg and The Master both work but if the length of the object is 1 values are 0.

This result comes out of a sheet, I think the best approach is to get the last and first row, if there is only 1 row, returns, if they are more than 1, calculate difference.

**This is the main sheet array**

```
[[2019,7,10,13]
,[2020,15,30,35]
,[2020,44,55,66]
,[2020,15,29,36]
,[2021,12,14,16]
,[2021,44,55,66]
,[2021,14,16,26]]
```

Unfortunately I can't ask new questions

Comment: Where are you taking `a.length`?

Comment: From data, I just tried with Object.keys(x.a).length, length is 0, it should be 3.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const arr = [
  {
    year: '2020',
    data: [
      { a: '11', b: '22', c: '33' },
      { a: '44', b: '55', c: '66' },
      { a: '77', b: '88', c: '99' },
    ],
  },
  {
    year: '2021',
    data: [
      { a: '11', b: '22', c: '33' },
      { a: '44', b: '55', c: '66' },
      { a: '77', b: '88', c: '99' },
    ],
  },
  {
    year: '2022',
    data: [
      { a: '11', b: '22', c: '33' },
      { a: '44', b: '55', c: '66' },
      { a: '79', b: '88', c: '99' },
    ],
  },
  {
    year: '2023',
    data: [
      { a: '10', b: '22', c: '33' },
      { a: '44', b: '55', c: '66' },
      { a: '77', b: '88', c: '99' },
    ],
  },
];

arr.forEach((dObj) =>
  ((abc) =>
    (dObj.data = [abc[0], abc[abc.length - 1]].reduce(
      (abc1, abc2) => (
        Object.keys(abc1).forEach((key) => (abc1[key] = abc2[key] - abc1[key])),
        abc1
      )
    )))(dObj.data)
);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine but unfortunately I have to change my approach. The data is in a sheet and to get to this step I could do it differently. I will ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Do I get you correctly...
Second scenario

```
year 2020: a = 5-11= 6
```

but

```
year 2022: a= 26- 23 = 3, not 6
```

Is it mistake or I didn't get the logic?
If mistake than do this with third scenario (not very elegant):

```
function myFunction() {
       var arr = [
   {"year":"2020","data":[{"a":"5","b":"6","c":"7"},{"a":"8","b":"9","c":"10"},{"a":"110","b":"12","c":"13"}]}
  ,{"year":"2021","data":[{"a":"14","b":"15","c":"16"},{"a":"17","b":"18","c":"19"},{"a":"2","b":"21","c":"22"}]}
  ,{"year":"2022","data":[{"a":"23","b":"24","c":"25"},{"a":"44","b":"55","c":"66"},{"a":"8","b":"27","c":"28"}]}
  ,{"year":"2023","data":[{"a":"29","b":"30","c":"31"},{"a":"32","b":"33","c":"34"},{"a":"19","b":"29","c":"31"}]}
]
  const output = arr.map((yearObj) => {
  const { year, data } = yearObj;
  const last = data[data.length - 1];
  const first = data[0];
  const diffObj = {};
  for (const key in last) {
    if (last.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      diffObj[key] = last[key] - first[key];
    }
  }
  return { year, data: diffObj };
});
Logger.log(output)
}
```

The result:

```
    [{data={a=105.0, b=6.0, c=6.0}, year=2020}, {data={c=6.0, a=-12.0, b=6.0}, year=2021}, {year=2022, data={b=3.0, c=3.0, a=-15.0}}, {data={c=0.0, a=-10.0, b=-1.0}, year=2023}]
```

Comment: Hi, this approach doesn't work properly. If first value of a is 11 and last value is 11, 11-11=0, instead I receive 33. May you try?

Comment: I need to find difference between last value (not max value) and first value (not min value). Last value can be less than the first value

Comment: @Zimox what value do you expect if the last value is less than the first value - please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76109449/edit) your question and add the scenarios and expected results for such scenarios.

Comment: Basically I have to filter from a list of data with the values of the first row and the values of the last row, making the difference between the last row and the first. I converted the rows and columns to json format but I'm not sure it's the quickest solution. However the difference more be negative

Comment: Thanks, it works but unfortunately I have to change my approach. The data is in a sheet and to get to this step I could do it differently. I will ask a new question